# store and delete text file locally ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, file

I'm new to ios(android) developer. Do you have some specific file storage in the app's sandbox where i can store or delete some additional files?

I need to write to file some logs of handled exceptions and then store them to server when starting the application. After successful delievery to server, i want to delete this log file, and create new one, and do it again and again.

Comment: No, but there are areas where you can store files.  Why haven't you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Also consider `NSDocumentDirectory` and `NSCachesDirectory`.

Comment: what about permissions? i have rights to read and write to this folder?

Comment: Yes, inside from your application. Therefore they are.